# Scale down images carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

How to scale down original image to 10% quality keeping the original dimensions. I don't want to resize it, just reduce the quality. The purpose is to reduce the filesize. I am using `carrierwave` with `Rails`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method to your Uploader class and then call that with process, like so:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick # <-- Use this line, if you're using RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick # <-- Use this line, if you're using MiniMagick

  process :optimize_image

  private

  def optimize_image
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.quality 10
      img
    end
  end

end
```

Or you can create a more dynamic method called 'quality' that accepts the desired quality as an argument as seen in this Carrierwave wiki example: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Specify-the-image-quality